# Post on facebook without api but by http requests

Tags: python, facebook, http, post, python-requests

I'm looking for a way to post status on Facebook just by giving the username(email), password, and the status I'm going to post as inputs.
This is my actual code. (headers are examples, they're wrong)

The code isn't working because i don't know what to send and where to send it. (http requests)

How can I improve it?

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (username, passw)
s.headers.update({'username': 'Liam', "password": "*********","status": "this is a status"})

print s.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers={'username': 'Liam', "password": "*********","status": "that's a status"})
```

Comment: Is this code not working? What is the issue?

Comment: i dont know how many and wich requests to send and their headers @ChadS.

Comment: Selenium would be like shooting to a mosquito with a cannon, but you could give it a try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this for posting in a Facebook group. It's partially based in a script which doesnt work anymore for uploading pictures to a Facebook page.

Notes:
1- User group ID is hardcoded. You can get in by querying a website which translates Facebook group name into ID and incorporate it in the script. I've made that for other scripts, didnt care to do it in this.
2 - I just deleted comments on the fly and changed a few things before posting it here for it not to be a mess. It might complain about something (can't run it on the cellphone), but in general it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import datetime
import json
import logging
import re
import random
import requests
import shutil
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq


def main(username, password, page):

    logging.basicConfig(filename='imgur2fb.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

    session = requests.session()

    uid, dtsg = login(session, username, password)

    grupoID = "580864492030176" #(Fijo)

    postToFacebook(session, dtsg, grupoID, "Prueba 98765",uid)


def login(session, username, password):

    '''
    Login to Facebook
    '''

    # Navigate to the Facebook homepage
    response = session.get('https://facebook.com')

    # Construct the DOM
    dom = pq(response.text)

    # Get the lsd value from the HTML. This is required to make the login request
    lsd = dom('[name="lsd"]').val()

    # Perform the login request
    response = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', data={
        'lsd': lsd,
        'email': username,
        'pass': password,
        'default_persistent': '0',
        'timezone': '-60',
        'lgndim': '',
        'lgnrnd': '',
        'lgnjs': '',
        'locale':'en_GB',
        'qsstamp': ''
    })

    '''
    Get the users ID and fb_dtsg token. The fb_dtsg token is required when making requests as a logged in user. It
    never changes, so we only need to grab this token once.

    If the login was successful a cookie 'c_user' is set by Facebook. If the login failed, the 'c_user' cookie
    will not be present. This will raise an exception.
    '''
    try:
        uid = session.cookies['c_user']
        dtsg = re.search(r'(type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="([0-9a-zA-Z-_:]+)")', response.text).group(1)

        dtsg = dtsg[dtsg.find("value")+6:]
        dtsg = dtsg[1:-1]

    except KeyError:
        raise Exception('Login Failed!')

    return uid, dtsg


def postToFacebook(session, dtsg, pageID, message,uID):

    data = {
        "[0]":"",   
        "[1]":"",
        "__ajax__":"",  #AYmIVqL7VfighmiRmFWSBGl6Aucepl7b-I5RPZaAyEEk7rT-6UQQ2zOpUe433RwWQaZACpH9gA--j8otSHry0_Kmd6iZtK2QHyufgZ59eoLtwA
        "__dyn":"",#    1KQdAm1mxu4UpwDF3GAgy6K6Acgy6F8mxq2K2i5U9EowRwFzohxO3J0GwywlEf8lwJwsE2xCyoe8hwv9E887u4o2CyUb852i1gw
        "__req":"",#    e
    "__user":uID,
    "album_fbid":"0",
    "appid":"", 
    "at":"",    
    "backdated_day":"", 
    "backdated_month":"",   
    "backdated_year":"",
    "ch":"",    
    "csid":"",  #b4f44053-0da3-46b8-8c54-782fb428a624
    "fb_dtsg":dtsg, #AQEHse9gjZYA:AQGng01UK1fd
    "freeform_tag_place":"",    
    "fs":"",    
    "internal_extra":"",
    "is_backdated":"",  
    "iscurrent":"", 
    "linkUrl":"",   
    "link_no_change":"",    
    "loc":"{}",
    "m_sess":"",    
    "message":message,# prueba 88
    "npa":"",   
    "npc":"",   
    "npn":"",   
    "npp":"",   
    "npw":"",
    "npz":"",   
    "ogaction":"",  
    "oghideattachment":"",  
    "ogicon":"",    
    "ogobj":"", 
    "ogphrase":"",  
    "ogsuggestionmechanism":"",
    "rating":"0",
    "scheduled_am_pm":"",   
    "scheduled_day":"",
    "scheduled_hours":"",   
    "scheduled_minutes":"", 
    "scheduled_month":"",   
    "scheduled_year":"",
    "sid":"",   
    "source_loc":"composer_group",
    "target":pageID,
    "text_[0]":"",
    "text_[1]":"",  
    "unpublished_content_type":"0",
    "waterfall_id":"988d79257398ec678a8e287046f322ca",  # Esto cambia en cada logueo??
    "waterfall_source":"composer_group"

    }


    response = session.post('https://m.facebook.com/a/group/post/add/?gid='+pageID+'&refid=18',

                            #params=params,
                            data=data,
                            #headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
                            headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

    print response


try:
    main(username='j*****', password='****', page='https://www.facebook.com/groups/linkdelgrupo')
except Exception, e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print e
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work even if I am not an admin of the group?